# Restart Delphi TThread that lives the entire app lifetime

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have created a class that derives from TThread, because I wish to do some async stuff, however to avoid having to create another class, I built the entire thing around that thread class. Not sure if this is good practice or not, and if I cant get this to work, well then I suppose I have no choice but to recode..

**The problem:** I create the Thread on FormCreate, assign some properties, and I Free it on FormDestroy. In the Thread's constructor, I set `FreeOnTerminate = False`. When I click on a button on my Form, I `Start();` the Thread. Okay, so it runs as expected, an error occurs (expected!), its being passed to my error handling event, and it **appears to** terminate. I then click the button again, and I get a `Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread` error.

How can I finish the thread without freeing it, and enabling me to start it again?

Comment: If you want a thread to live the entire app lifetime, why let it terminate(or appear to), and try to start it again?  You could use a while (true) do begin..end; loop.  If you want to control the thread body run by means of your button click, look at TEvent, TSimpleEvent or TSemaphore.

Comment: @Martin - I start it again for the Execute routine to run. :)

Comment: Put the while loop in the TThread.execute!  At the top of the loop, wait on a TEvent, TSimpleEvent or Tsemaphore wait object.  When you want the thread to do whatever is inside the loop, signal the wait object from your Button.onClick() event.  You only need to start() the thread once - at the end of your constructor.

Comment: ..or not.  Aparrently, TThread.start is meant to be called outside the TThread constructor, so my advice was bad :((  So either call the constructor and then Start() or use the 'old system' of creating the thread suspended, (inherited create(true)), at the start of the constructor and calling resume() at the end.  TBH, sometimes Borland/Embarcadero seem to be trying to make threading as awkward as possible.  There was no problem with resume(), as long as it was only ever used at the end of a TThread constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't restart a thread once it is finished/terminated. In that case you should just create a new instance if the thread again like you did in FormCreate.

Comment: That kinda ruins the purpose of Properties.. Oh well. :)

Comment: You *can* use properties with TThread descendants, but your setters/getters are unlikely to be as simple as just setting Ffields, especially if the thread is going to run for the lifetime of the app.  Quite often, locking/queueing of the property set is going to be necessary to avoid races/corruption.

Comment: "You can't restart a thread once it is finished/terminated" - WHAT ??????? That is poor design of TThread.

Answer (score 5):

Catch the error in the thread, handle it there and then let the thread continue the work. To handle the error you could simply queue a method to the main thread to report the error, for example. I hope you aren't letting exceptions leave your thread Execute method.

Comment: I am basically firing an OnError event, which is assigned in the Main thread, and it works absolutely gorgeously. :)

Comment: Isn't it easier to do it the way I suggest? You are already catching errors.  Just handle them and continue running the thread. Maybe I don't understand the problem.

Comment: the problem is that I would like my thread to run the entire lifetime, so I did not have to set properties again - but doing that disabled me from reusing the same instance, as I can only call Start once.

Comment: @Jeff I'm proposing that you do indeed run the thread for the entire lifetime of your process. I don't see why you need to terminate the thread and then start a new one.

Comment: The thread performs a request using IdHTTP, and to avoid UI hang, I used a Thread. The problem is, that once I press Start, it does what its supposed to, but when I press start again (after it has finished, dont worry) I get the "Cannot call start on a running or suspended thread"

Comment: @Jeff Why are you trying to start it again. If you want it to run for the entire lifetime of the thread then don't ever return from `TMyThread.Execute` unless the app is quitting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1548/discussion-between-jeff-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: I hate this idea of continuing discussion in chat. How does that help other readers? I'd like to have a preference on my profile that says, I don't ever do chat!

Comment: The solution is what is called a "state machine", where the thread waits for some work to do, does it, and then sleeps until triggered again. The idea of a single thread like this is quite normal.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way that I implement it:

```
procedure TAPIRequest.DoRequest;
begin
  FBusy := True;
  Resume;
end;


procedure TAPIRequest.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  while not Terminated do begin
    HttpError := False;

    try
      Response := HTTP.Post(URL, Params);
      ParseResponse;

    except
      HttpError := True;
    end;

    if Assigned(OnResponse) then
      OnResponse();

    FBusy := False;
    Suspend;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyThread: TMyThread;
  Event: TEvent;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Event := TEvent.Create(nil,true,false, '');
  MyThread := TMyThread.Create(False);
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while True do
    begin
      Event.WaitFor(Infinite);

      // do something

      Event.ResetEvent;
    end;
end;

procedure RestartThread;
begin
    Event.SetEvent;
// if you need check thread status, wait or run, use here 
// if Event.WaitFor(0) = ...(wrTimeout, wrSignaled)
end;
```